# iCloud says that backups are using 3 GB of space, but there are no backups

Tags: icloud, backup, storage

My iCloud account shows that I have ~3 GB of backups, but when I check on all devices using this account, backups are off and no backups are showing.
[image: Storage information]
*The storage bar.*

[image: No backups]
*The backups list... empty!*

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are looking at the iCloud info in System Preferences on an Apple laptop or desktop. Inside System Preferences, after you click on iCloud, you then click on Manage in the lower right corner. When that window comes up, the top option is highlighted but not necessarily selected. If it's not selected, the backups will not show in the right column. Click on Backups to make sure it is selected.

I also would recommend signing into www.iCloud.com and verifying that you have no backups in the cloud. As many of these devices back up on their own, it seems unlikely that you would have no backups unless you recently deleted them.

Comment: I clicked in the left-hand side and still no backups. No backups appear on any of my other devices, although iCloud still reports backups as using space.

Comment: Did you check www.icloud.com and see if there are backups that, perhaps, you are not seeing on the computer? Do you know if your other devices are set up to automatically backup via iCloud? I still think it's strange that you wouldn't have any backups. It seems more likely that they aren't showing up for some reason.